# Display Username at my asp.net after authenticating user from sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to show logged in user name at my asp.net page what is the query or anything required to do so help me

```
CREATE PROCEDURE validate_user    
    @Username VARCHAR(20),    
      @Password VARCHAR(20)    
AS    
BEGIN    
      SET NOCOUNT ON;    
      DECLARE @UserId INT    

      select count(*)from UserArtTable where UserName = @Username and passwd = @Password    
End
```

My this stored procedure only authenticates if the user exists or not
what i want is, if user exists then his/her username that i have stored in database should be populated at asp.net page
what code i have to write in C# or at client side with jquery i am stuck here. I have simply no clue
I am working in 3 tiers could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

We can use output parameters in stored procedure to return username from a single query.  Use this stored procedure.

```
       CREATE PROCEDURE validate_user    
        @Username VARCHAR(20),    
        @Password VARCHAR(20),
        @UsernameOutput VARCHAR(20) output
    AS    
    BEGIN    
          SET NOCOUNT ON;    
    declare @test int
      select @test=count(*) from UserArtTable where UserName = @Username and passwd = @Password 
      if(@test>0)
          select @UsernameOutput=UserName from UserArtTable where UserName = @Username and passwd = @Password 
    End
```

Normally, in practical scenarios we will have two stored procedures one for verifying credentials and one to load user information after the login.  If this is your requirement, use the above code.

This should work for you.  If it does *Please mark it as answer*.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can follow following steps to display user name:

1. Validate the username (xxx) by using the stored proc you mentioned above
2. Get the user from database using another PROC as below:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE get_user    
    @Username VARCHAR(20)    
    AS    
    BEGIN    
      SET NOCOUNT ON;    
      DECLARE @UserId INT    

      select * from UserArtTable where UserName = @Username 
    End
```

3. Now use the usename you got from database to display on the page you want

This is a generalized solution and you need to create following methods in C#:

1. bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
2. UserObject GetUser(string userName)

Comment: what is the point of writing another sp...? and if used then how to call two stored procedures in one connection at the same time under same click

Comment: It's all about separation of concerns.  My point was it is always best to separate `ValidateUser` from `GetUser`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the count from the stored procedure. So just  get result by `ExecuteScalar()` or `ExecuteNonQuery()` and place a check of count like this:

```
    ...
    int countResult = ExecuteNonScalar();

    if(countResult > 0)
    {
         Display(userName); 
         //userName here is the same that you have passed to your Stored Procedure. 
    }
```